# Remove an action being called inside a function (PHP, WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a PHP file like this:

```
final class FLBuilderFonts {

    /**
     * An array of fonts / weights.
     * @var array
     */
    static private $fonts = array();

    static private $enqueued_google_fonts_done = false;

    /**
     * @since 1.9.5
     * @return void
     */
    static public function init() {
        add_filter( 'the_content', __CLASS__ . '::combine_google_fonts', 11 );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', __CLASS__ . '::combine_google_fonts', 10000 );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', __CLASS__ . '::enqueue_google_fonts', 9999 );
        add_filter( 'wp_resource_hints', __CLASS__ . '::resource_hints', 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'wp_head', array( __CLASS__, 'preload' ), 5 );
    }

    static public function preload() {
        $fa_version = FLBuilder::get_fa5_version();
        $icons      = array(
            'foundation-icons' => array(
                'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.woff',
            ),
            'font-awesome-5'   => array(
                FL_BUILDER_URL . 'fonts/fontawesome/' . $fa_version . '/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2',
                FL_BUILDER_URL . 'fonts/fontawesome/' . $fa_version . '/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2',
                FL_BUILDER_URL . 'fonts/fontawesome/' . $fa_version . '/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2',
            ),
        );

        // if using pro cdn do not preload as we have no idea what the url will be.
        if ( get_option( '_fl_builder_enable_fa_pro', false ) || apply_filters( 'fl_enable_fa5_pro', false ) ) {
            unset( $icons['font-awesome-5'] );
        }

        foreach ( $icons as $key => $preloads ) {
            if ( wp_style_is( $key, 'enqueued' ) ) {
                foreach ( $preloads as $url ) {
                    printf( '<link rel="preload" href="%s" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">' . "\n", $url );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How to disable this line by command?

```
add_action( 'wp_head', array( __CLASS__, 'preload' ), 5 );
```

I've tried inserting various remove_action commands into the theme's functions.php file, but it didn't work. Hope someone will help me.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
global $FLBuilderFonts;
remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $FLBuilderFonts, 'preload' ) );
```

Or

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_preload_action', 10, 1 );
function remove_preload_action(){
    $FLBuilderFonts = new FLBuilderFonts();
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $FLBuilderFonts, 'preload' ) );
}
```

if still does not work try to change the priority of action.

Comment: Thanks for your help but they are not working. :(